# Installing precompiled ruby gems for the right ruby version?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I need to install some ruby gems with native extensions on machines with no compiler, and I have to do so for a few different ruby versions.

My plan is to have some CI pipeline to download the gem source, compile it and uploade it on a private Rubygems repository.

I'm considering using [gem-compiler](https://github.com/luislavena/gem-compiler) to build the gems. I see that, by default, gems are bound to the minor Ruby version (e.g. 2.5), and won't work on different versions. There's a command line option to disable the ABI lock, but it looks scary and comes with a do not use warning.

I've been reading the Rubygems API and command documentation, but I couldn't find a way to arrange different binaries for the same gem version so that the right one will be downloaded for the right ruby version.

Is this at all possible? How?

Or should I just go for something more primitive, like having a different private repository for each Ruby version?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is possible through the rubygems API to mix different binaries. I think you refer primarily to e. g. .so files on linux? If so then you could try to actually compile on your local machine through different ruby versions (use rvm or any other ways to have multiple ruby versions; I compile into versioned directories such as /Programs/Ruby/2.5.2 etc), then build the bindings. Once you have the .so file you could also just put it into the ruby gem; I abuse lib/ for this a lot.

I am not sure how to ensure that it can be easily installed on the target machine, but you could always add some bin/ ruby file that does the installation part.

I guess the first step would be that you can ensure that the correct version is built; once that works, distributing that should be possible. Rubygems isn't doing something magic either.

Edit: Are you referring to windows perhaps? Since you linked to luis, and luis did some work on windows in the past. Windows is probably making things a bit more difficult ... the task seems not trivial.